# How to get the checked radio input of a group without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a group of radio button inputs like that:

```html
<input type="radio" name="fruit" id="pear">
<input type="radio" name="fruit" id="apple">
<input type="radio" name="fruit" id="banana">
```

Is there a way to get the id of the checked radio button input **without** jQuery?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same selector: `[name=fruit]:checked` can be used by document.querySelector - supported by IE8+ and other modern browsers

```js
console.log(
  $("[name=fruit]:checked").attr("id"), // jQuery
  document.querySelector("[name=fruit]:checked").id // plain JS
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="fruit" id="pear" checked>
<input type="radio" name="fruit" id="apple">
<input type="radio" name="fruit" id="banana">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code. No jquery required.

```
var fruits = document.getElementsByName("fruit");

var selectedFruit;

for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
   if(fruits[i].checked)
   selectedFruit = fruits[i].id;
 }
console.log(selectedFruit);
```

Comment: Yes I thought about that but I wondered if there wasn't a shorter solution.

Comment: Old Skool ;) There has been a shorter solution since IE8 :)