# Getting value of active/checked rating

Tags: javascript, html, input, rating-system

```
   <div class="star-rating">
      <input type="radio" id="5-stars" name="rating" value="5" />
      <label for="5-stars" class="star">&#9733;</label>
      <input type="radio" id="4-stars" name="rating" value="4" />
      <label for="4-stars" class="star">&#9733;</label>
      <input type="radio" id="3-stars" name="rating" value="3" />
      <label for="3-stars" class="star">&#9733;</label>
      <input type="radio" id="2-stars" name="rating" value="2" />
      <label for="2-stars" class="star">&#9733;</label>
      <input type="radio" id="1-star" name="rating" value="1" />
      <label for="1-star" class="star">&#9733;</label>
    </div>
      <button id="btn" onclick="myFunction()"> Submit </button>

  </div> 
<script>
      function myFunction(){
      let rating = document.querySelector();  //what should I do here ?
       console.log(rating);
     }
</script>
```

I wanted the value of the rating that the user submits i.e if he submits 3 stars, I wanted the value 3 in javascript so that I would display a popup of "thank you ! you have submitted 3 stars."

Comment: `let rating = document.querySelector("[name=rating]:checked").value;`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the checked radio input of a group without jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536564/how-to-get-the-checked-radio-input-of-a-group-without-jquery)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of the selected radio button, you can use the querySelector method to select the checked radio button and then access its value property.

```html
<div class="star-rating">
      <input type="radio" id="5-stars" name="rating" value="5" />
      <label for="5-stars" class="star">★</label>
      <input type="radio" id="4-stars" name="rating" value="4" />
      <label for="4-stars" class="star">★</label>
      <input type="radio" id="3-stars" name="rating" value="3" />
      <label for="3-stars" class="star">★</label>
      <input type="radio" id="2-stars" name="rating" value="2" />
      <label for="2-stars" class="star">★</label>
      <input type="radio" id="1-star" name="rating" value="1" />
      <label for="1-star" class="star">★</label>
    </div>
    <button id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        const rating = document.querySelector(
          'input[name="rating"]:checked',
        ).value;
        console.log(rating);
        alert(`Thank you! You have submitted ${rating} stars.`);
      }
    </script>
```